# Amazon Redshift: Make COPY command fail if there is a missing column as key in json data

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am loading a JSON data from S3 into Redshift using the COPY command:

```
COPY <table> FROM '<s3 path of input json data>'
    CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<>;aws_secret_access_key=<>'
    GZIP format as json '<s3 path of jsonpathfile>';
```

What I want is that the COPY command should fail, or atleast should raise a warning, when a column of the Redshift table is missing as a key in the input json. What I mean is, if the table has, say, two columns A and B and input json has only one column B, COPY should fail or raise a warning saying column A missing. Right now what it does is, it sets the missing column A values as NULL and copies rest of the columns (B). So, one obvious workaround is to set all the columns as NOT NULL while CREATING the table. But I do not want to do that because in my data I can have a JSON like `{"A" : null, "B" : "something"}`. But in this case key 'A' is indeed present, then also it will fail as it is NULL but as per schema it is supposed to be NOT NULL. I want it to fail only when I receive a JSON such as `{"B":"something"}` i.e. key A is not present at all in the JSON.

Is there any other neat way to achieve that using the COPY command?

I also tried the `auto` option as follows, with same results:

```
COPY <table> FROM '<s3 path of input json data>'
    CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<>;aws_secret_access_key=<>'
    GZIP format as json 'auto';
```

Comment: "So, one obvious workaround is to set all the columns as NOT NULL while CREATING the table. But I do not want to do that." --> you will most likely get better answers if you explain _why_ you don't want to do that?

Comment: I do not want to do that because in my data I can have a JSON like `{"A" : null, "B" : "something"}`. But in this case key 'A' is indeed present, then also it will fail as it is NULL but as per schema it is supposed to be NOT NULL. I want it to fail only when I receive a JSON such as `{"B":"something"}`. I will edit the question to reflect the reason.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, now it makes much more sense! Without that information, the answer would likely be, "not null". But in your specific case, I understand that your properties can be in 1 of 3 states: they exist and have a value ("something"), they exist and don't have a value (null), or they don't exist. A few more questions: in your JSON, do all the elements have the exact same structure, or can it vary? (ie, if first element has attribute A and B, is it guaranteed that all will have A and B?)

Comment: Ideally it should have all the attributes unless someone changes the JSON structure.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any [option](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY-alphabetical-parm-list.html) to do this, but couldn't you simply pre-process or validate your data prior loading it? A [JSON schema validator](http://json-schema.org/) would seem rather appropriate here.